# JPA set timestamp generated by database but not CURRENTTIME or UPDATETIME

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa

I have a class like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Event")
public class Event {

  @Transient
  public static final long MAX_TIMESTAMP = 253402214400000L; // 9999-12-31 00:00:00
  private Date creationTime;
  private Date expiryTime;
  private String otherValue;

  public Event(int timeout, String otherValue){
    this.creationTime = new Date();
    this.expiryTime = (timeout == 0 ? new Date(MAX_TIMESTAMP) : new Date(creationTime.getTime() + SECONDS.toMillis(timeout)));
    this.otherValue = otherValue;
  }
}
```

I call save() methed in CrudRepository and save this data.

and I have a ScheduledExecutorService to find out some timeout events:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Event t WHERE t.expiryTime < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
  List<Event> findTimeoutEvents();
```

this CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is database's time, but expiryTime is not. It means that I must make their time is same.sometimes, the application and database are not in the same machine, I can not make sure their time is same.

Can I set "expiryTime" generated by database? How can I pass the parameter "timeout" to database.

the database maybe postgresql or mysql.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I am not sure your code works, since instance of `java.util.Date` (if expiry time is `java.util.Date` object) can not be compared to `int` 0.

As for generating an `expiryTime`, yes, you obviously can. Check out how do [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) work.

Also I would like to add, that if you use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, you may annotate `creationTime` field with `@CreationTimestamp` annotation. But I would personally set default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` on db side.

Comment: Think you'll find that `@CreationTimestamp` is not in the JPA API, and is in fact in a particular JPA provider (and the OP doesn't state which one he uses, so you can't go that way).

Comment: @BillyFrost you are right, it is in hibernate's one, but since OP put tags `spring` and `jpa`, I assumed that he/she uses `spring-jpa` which includes hibernate's libraries. But I shall edit my answer.

Comment: "spring-data-jpa" uses whichever JPA provider the user wants FWIW

Comment: thanks for your answer. And I made a mistake. I wrote a wrong code here.yes, I use spring-jpa.Thank you. I will edit my question.